# Add the "Add to wishlist" button to Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I use the plugin TI WooCommerce Wishlist. You need to add a wishlist button to the product. Output shortcode `<?php echo do_shortcode('[ti_wishlist_add to wishlist product_id=""]');?>` . How can I get the current product id ? Maybe there are other plugins ?

Comment: Tried it , but the wish list just disappears <?php echo esc_attr(do_shortcode('[ti_wishlists_addtowishlist id=' . $post->ID . ']')); ?>

Answer (score 0):

If You want to show the wishlist icon on the default product page then, please Follow this Doc [TI WooCommerce Wishlist](https://templateinvaders.com/documentation/ti-woocommerce-wishlist-free/?utm_source=wordpressorg&utm_content=documentation#button)

[Here Is the settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssTTf.png)

Or If you are running a custom loop then you how to get the id in WordPress loop.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is that the plugin does not automatically display the add to wishlist button, since I am making a template for woocommerce from scratch. Is there any way to output a shortcode button. If I manually add a short code with the product ID ?php echo do_shortcode('[ti_wishlist_add to wishlist product_id="73"]');?> , the button appears on the site, but it adds only one product.

Comment: Do you want to add multiple products at once?

Comment: no, I need each product to have its own button and add the current product to favorites

Answer (score 0):

First you need to change some settings. Go to: Product listing Button Settings -> Button Position -> and select Custom position with code.

I was searching for something like this. I solved adding this shortcode into the custom loop design. [ti_wishlists_addtowishlist loop=yes].